# Estimating Contingent Probabilities from Time-Series Data

Tags: regression, time-series, probability, conditional-probability

This is my first post. Apologies in advance if anything is off. I wanted to see if anyone knows whether there is an accepted method for estimating contingent probabilities from time-series data.

The context of the problem is that there is a call centre and a website with the call centre's number. There is time-series statistics for calls to the call centre (from a call logging system) and visits to the website (from Google Analytics).

A regression shows the website visits correlate strongly to the call centre data. I want to be able to estimate the probability of someone visiting the website calling the call centre though, for the purposes of linking to a Markov chain.

Is there any acceptable method for doing this. Googling did not seem to help.

Comment: How about P = no. of calls/ no. of visits.

Comment: Can you augment the post with some plots? Look into autocorrelation and cross-correlation, time-series regression.  Maybe even some version of logistic regression.